# Is there a way to find a 'friendly' name for an executable given its path?

Tags: .net, registry

I'm creating a UI that has buttons that start a number of .EXE files in their own thread.

I know the path to the .EXE files, but I'm wanting to display a friendly application name rather than the file name of the executable. Most of the applications that are referenced are big name applications like Microsoft Word or Skype; not just in house EXE files.

As an example, my path may be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE"
```

But in my UI I want to display a button with "Word" on it.

I've noticed that in the registry many applications store a `FriendlyAppName` in an area of the registry that I can access as follows:

```
command.Text = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue
    (
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\" + 
    IO.Path.GetFileName(path),
    "FriendlyAppName",
    IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
    )
```

But for many applications the name isn't present. Does anyone know if there is a better way to get a FriendlyAppName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FileDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.filedescription.aspx) property of the `FileVersionInfo` class.

```cs
var info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
               @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\winword.exe");
Console.WriteLine(info.FileDescription);
```

Prints:

> Microsoft Word

You might think the `ProductName` property makes more sense, but if the application belongs to a suite, `ProductName` will hold the name of the suite. For example in the case of Word, it would say `Microsoft Office`.

Comment: Thanks, that gives much better results than part of the registry I found :)